# how to set 301 redirection for URL having '?' like characters in URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I want to redirect all URLs having `id` after `'emailthisone?'`.

forexampleL:

`http://news4u.com/emailmeone?id=1234'` . When this url is accessed it must be redirected to `http;//news4u.com/new/emailmeone?id=1234`.

I tried to set `RedirectMatch 301 /emailmeone?(.*) http://news4u.com/new/emailmeone$1` But this will act even if '?' is after 'emailmeone'.

How to achieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch`, although the query string will get appended automatically, there's no check that the query string is actually `id=something`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/emailmeone$ /new/emailmeone
```

The `?id=1234` gets automatically appended to the end of the target. You could vet the `id` bit if you use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=[0-9]
RewriteRule ^emailmeone$ /new/emailmeone [L,QSA]
```

Comment: but this will also redirect all the link which will not have ?id like query string in URL. I mean `http://news4u.com/emailmeone` also. But i need to redirect only urls like `http://news4u.com/emailmeone?id=1234`

Comment: @NaanuManu Correct, that's why there's the 2nd option (with mod_rewrite) that actually checks. You aren't able to check the query string in a `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch`.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id
  RewriteRule ^emailmeone$ /alerts/emailmeone[R=301,L]` will this work different. I have removed [0-9] and checking if the query string is having `id` or not. still both are not working.